# Unable to automatically select Windows Services settings in Unattended XML

Tags: xml, windows, installation, unattend-file

I am struggling to find a way of automating the install of Windows 10. I have an unattended.xml file that handles creating the disk partition, the user, password and everything else. It's nearly fully automated but I still have the following settings showing up that require user input:

1. "Let Microsoft and apps use your location"
2. "Find my Device"
3. "Send Diagnostic data to Microsoft"
4. "Improve inking and typing"
5. "Get tailored experiences with diagnostic data"
6. "Let apps use advertising ID"

[image: Settings that still aren't automated]

I've tried several different combinations in the XML file to automate these, I've also tried to capture a new install WIM with all of these settings already set but they reappear again on a fresh installation.

Any help to have this automated would be really appreciated.